# python3 elif syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime, syntax

Ошибка:

```bsh
     File "main.py", line 56
    elif datetime.datetime.todaye().isoweekday() == 2:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['today'])
def send_welcome(message):
    if datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday() == 1:
        bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/1.txt')    
    elif datetime.datetime.todaye().isoweekday() == 2:
        bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/2.txt')
    elif datetime.datetime.todaye().isoweekday() == 3:
        bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/3.txt')
    elif datetime.datetime.todaye().isoweekday() == 4:
        bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/4.txt')
    elif datetime.datetime.todaye().isoweekday() == 5:
        bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/5.txt')
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скобки не закрываете.

Comment: Да и дальше там `todaye()` тоже ошибку даст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
bot.reply_to(message, open_file('msg/1.txt')
```

Здесь нет закрывающей скобки